# Plain permalinks not working!

Tags: posts, permalinks, redirect, htaccess

For my wordpress website plain permalinks are not working. The post url is changing but when we click on the post its not redirecting to the post page. It will be in the home page itself.

For example:

```
http://example.com/?p=14523
```

If I change the permalinks to other custom formats, it works correctly and showing the posts page. For example:

```
http://example.com/2018/09/01/postname/
```

I tried creating a new `.htaccess` file after changing the permalinks to plain.
Still not working.

Comment: What does your htaccess look like, standard or did you customise it?

Comment: standard one    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: basically wordpress default canonical permalink is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain permalinks of the form `/?p=14523` (or `/index.php?p=14523`) don't necessarily need any `.htaccess` file since they don't require mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL (unlike the the *custom permalinks* you mention).

However, for a URL of the form `/?p=14523` (as opposed to `/index.php?p=14523`), where you don't explicitly state the index document (ie. `index.php`) in the URL then the `DirectoryIndex` must be correctly set on your server. This can be achieved in `.htaccess` using the following directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Normally, this is set by default on most servers, but sometimes it is not.

Answer (score 0):

delete .htaccess completely and reset permalinks, I have faced similar incidents it did the trick.